# Encoding limit exceeded

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a pretty lengthy script that takes either user input or data from a .csv file to create AD accounts. Not all the time, but sometimes I receive the following error while running it: 
New-ADUser : The server has returned the following error: encoding limit exceeded.

Is there a limit on the amount of variables I can use? Because I do have quite a few.. here's what the sample code looks like where it sometimes get stuck:

```
If($GuardAccount){
    If($Clone){
        If($Attribute6){
            $newuser = New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Username -Enabled $true -Name $DisplayName -Path $Path -AccountPassword $Password `
            -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName -Initials $Initials -DisplayName $DisplayName -City $City `
            -Company $Company -Department $Department -Country $Country -State $State `
            -StreetAddress $Street -PostalCode $Postal -OfficePhone $Telephone -Fax $Fax -Description $Description `
            -Title $Title -Office $Office -Instance $Cloneuser -UserPrincipalName "$Username@business.com" -PassThru `
            -OtherAttributes @{
                'extensionattribute6'=$Attribute6;
            }
```

...

So what does encoding limit exceeded mean? Is there any way around it?
I've tried googling for answers but there doesn't seem to be much info on this error.

Comment: Are there any patterns of length of the data of the user details being created where it returns this error? I also believe there is a limit to how many users u can create in a single go but it should be pretty high.

Comment: No, it seems to happen specifically when a particular variable was given a $true value.. Basically if $true create account this way, if $false create that way. The weird thing is though running that section of the script manually works fine.

Comment: Have you tried running the code by stepping through it using ISE? like when you do a debug. If the only difference you can find is the speed of execution, try introducing a delay ahead of the culprit code. Since your whole code isnt here, we can only guess.

Comment: Yes that's fair. I was hoping someone would just recognize the error and what it meant.

Comment: May I also suggest using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) when you have so many parameters? This helps making the code more readable and also you don't have to deal with the easy to overlook backticks.